# Use url args in views, is it possible?

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to use url arguments in views (not templates, I know how to do that).

So is it possible to use them like:

```
def item_link(self, item):
    return mainpage_url_name + "%s/%i" % (item.slug, item.cid)
```

mainpage_url_name - is of course defined in url patterns (as name variable)

I'm a total newb in Django...

Thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest you follow the [Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).  It is very well written and straight to the point.

Comment: I've been doing that, but I haven't been able to find my answer...

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to do?  The function you posted is not a view function because it doesn't take a request as its first parameter.

Comment: The function in the post is extracted from the Feed syndication. I'm trying to achieve that all the "fixed" paths would be in one place... urls.py and that every single "fixed" path would get returned from there... If that's even possible I know it is for templates...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should use names for your url patterns as [documented here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).

Then you can use [`reverse()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) to use these names in your views or methods.

---

Following your comments you are using the syndication framework.

Therefore you should make sure that you define `get_absolute_url()` for you models, ideally using the [permalink decorator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.permalink) (for a clean reversing of your urls).

Looking at the [example from Django's docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/syndication/#a-simple-example) that should be all that's necessary.

> To specify the contents of `<link>`, you
>   have two options. For each item in
>   items(), Django first tries calling
>   the item_link() method on the Feed
>   class. In a similar way to the title
>   and description, it is passed it a
>   single parameter, item. If that method
>   doesn't exist, Django tries executing
>   a get_absolute_url() method on that
>   object.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that but I couldn't get it to work. As I said I went through the documentation and then I posted the question... not the other way around...

Comment: "I've tried that but I couldn't get it to work" ... how do you expect somebody to help you if this is the whole information you provide? What about some error messages and some additional context infos?

Comment: I always get Give your Content class a get_absolute_url() method, or define an item_link() method in your Feed class.def get_absolute_url(self):
  return ('frontpage-news-show', (), {
   'news_slug': self.slug,
   'news_id': self.cid
  })